# C# Entity Framework call sp_spaceused

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

Here is my code:

```
public class CSpaceUsed
{
    string database_name { get; set; }
    string database_size { get; set; }
    string unallocated_space { get; set; }
    string reserved { get; set; }
    string data { get; set; }
    string index_size { get; set; }
    string unused { get; set; } 
}

public void  CheckDatabaseSize()
{
  var result = _dbEnergyContext.Database.SqlQuery<CSpaceUsed>("sp_spaceused @oneresultset = {0}", 1).ToList();
}
```

I get the correct result for all fields except for **unallocated_space** which is null. I have used the same column names from the result of SQL Query:

```
EXEC sp_spaceused @oneresultset = 1
```

but the column name **unallocated space** could not be used with C#, so I used underscore.

Any clue how to get unallocated space value?

I have read somewhere that this is an unsolved issue. Is that right, or is there a way to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to annotate your properties with the `Column` attribute in order to tell EF about the column name mapping.

```
public class CSpaceUsed
{
    string database_name { get; set; }
    string database_size { get; set; }
    [Column("unallocated space")]
    string unallocated_space { get; set; }
    string reserved { get; set; }
    string data { get; set; }
    string index_size { get; set; }
    string unused { get; set; } 
};
```

Comment: Thanks, from some reason it does not work for me. CSpaceUsed class is an helper class and is not the part of _dbEnergyContext, Could that be the reason?

Comment: that might be the case, the annotations will only work for entities that are part of the context I believe.